# double task if pattern matches in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I wander if I can do 2 different things for a single pattern match:
I'm reading a file with the following line:

```
(   1,<2010-01-12 15:19:51.32 +0100>,<marc>,<telescope1>,
```

I am trying this strategy:

```
open(FILE, "<tmpinp.txt");  
while (<FILE>){
    {$expstart = timelocal($6,$5,$4,$2,($3-1),$1) && $usr=$7} if
          /.+1,<(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}).*>,<(\S+)>,<(\S+)>.+\n/;
    };
close(FILE);
};
```

Thus I wanna get the epoch time and the username (marc in this example) 
in one run. It just doesnt work. Any help!?

Thanx a lot!

Answer (score 4):

The clearest way would be to use the non-postfix form of `if`:

```
while (<FILE>){
   if (/.+1,<(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}).*>,<(\S+)>,<(\S+)>.+\n/) {
      # this is a block; you can put as many statements in here as you want
      $expstart = timelocal($6,$5,$4,$2,($3-1),$1);
      $usr = $7;
   }
}
```

If you really, really want to use the postfix `if` for some reason, you could still use it with a block, thanks to `do`:

```
while (<FILE>){
   do {
      # this is a block; you can put as many statements in here as you want
      $expstart = timelocal($6,$5,$4,$2,($3-1),$1);
      $usr = $7;
   } if /.+1,<(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}).*>,<(\S+)>,<(\S+)>.+\n/;
}
```

Or you can combine the two statements into one in some esoteric manner. This can be useful for micro-optimizing a condition within a very tight loop. For example, you could use the comma operator to combine the two assignments:

```
while (<FILE>){
   ($expstart = timelocal($6,$5,$4,$2,($3-1),$1)), ($usr = $7)
      if /.+1,<(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}).*>,<(\S+)>,<(\S+)>.+\n/;
}
```

Or if you know `timelocal` will always return a single scalar value (never a list of zero, or more than one value), then you can use list assignment to set both `$expstart` and `$usr`:

```
while (<FILE>){
   ($expstart, $usr) = (timelocal($6,$5,$4,$2,($3-1),$1), $7)
      if /.+1,<(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}).*>,<(\S+)>,<(\S+)>.+\n/;
}
```

Or if you know `timelocal` will always be returning a "true" value (i.e not 0, or the empty string, or undef), you could use `&&` as you were attempting:

```
while (<FILE>){
   ($expstart = timelocal($6,$5,$4,$2,($3-1),$1)) && ($usr = $7)
      if /.+1,<(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}).*>,<(\S+)>,<(\S+)>.+\n/;
}
```

TIMTOWTDI.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Local;

open(FILE, "<tmpinp.txt");

while (<FILE>){
    if ($_ =~ /^.+1,<(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}).*?>,<(\S+)>,<(\S+)>.+$/) {
        print join(' => ', timelocal($6,$5,$4,$2,$3-1,$1), $7) . "\n";
    }
}

close(FILE);
```

Prints:

```
1291213191 => marc
```